# How to delete a clip (NOT merely silence a time range!) without moving the rest of the track?

Tags: audacity

Let's say I have selected a middle portion of a clip and cut it, and now I have three adjacent clips.

How do I delete the middle clip, but have everything after it remain where it was, instead of being moved?

"Silence" is not the answer here. The requirement is to be left with a gap between the clips where the deleted clip previously was, and exactly the length of the deleted clip.

Comment: You should say which software you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the software you are using.

In Audacity, it is called "[split delete](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/edit_menu_remove_special.html)" (Edit menu > Remove Special > split delete).